# Sending bulk emails in c # .net windows application

Tags: c#, winforms

My project is to send at least 100 mails an hour.

I have used for loop to retrieve emails from database and send email one by one.

But When I googled i find out that it will get time out after some time.So What is the method to use to hold the mail sending for a while and then restart the loop from hold position.Also,if the sending failed i should resend it.Should I use timer?

Please provide me any idea to complete this.

My sample code,

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
        String dbValues;
        foreach (DataRow row in globalClass1.dtgrid.Rows)
        {
            //String From DataBase(dbValues)
            dbValues = row["email"].ToString();

            list.Add(dbValues);


        }
using (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(mailserver, port))
        {
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(emailfrom, password);
            client.EnableSsl = true;

            MailMessage msg1 = new MailMessage();
            foreach (string row in list)
            {
                if (row != null)
                {
                    msg1=sendmail(row);
                    client.Send(msg1);
                    client.Dispose();
}
}}
```

Comment: What timeout are you talking about? Have you encountered a real problem or are you assuming, based on incomplete information?

Comment: In any case, you can use a *Queue*, ConcurrentQueue or ActionBlock to push emails on one end and process them from the other. No need to restart or hold position

Comment: In that loop I am able to send 30 mails.I don't  know anything about queue.Any sample examples,please.

Comment: *What is the full exception, including the stack trace?* Changing your code won't help you if there's a connectivity issue.

Comment: Your client timesout because it is open for to long, place the using inside the foreach, this will solve it

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**

You can simply [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144695(v=vs.110).aspx) multiple recipients to [`To`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.to(v=vs.110).aspx) property of [`MailMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var mail = new MailMessage();   
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("to@example.com"));
```

For example when you have a `list` that contains recipients, you can add theme all:

```
var mail = new MailMessage();

foreach (var item in list)
{
   mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(item));
}

mail.From = new MailAddress("from@example.com");
mail.Subject = "Subject";
mail.Body = "Body";

client.Send(mail);
```

**Option 2**

If you don't want to set all addresses using `To` or `Bcc` you can can use a `Task` to send emails this way:

```
public void SendMails(List<string> list)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            //Put all send mail codes here 
            //...
            //mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(item));
            //client.Send(mail);
        }
    });
}
```

**Option 3**

You can also use  [`SendMailAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194001(v=vs.110).aspx) to send mails.

Thanks to [`Panagiotis Kanavos`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos) to mention that this way is preferred instead of using `Task.Run` .

Comment: This will result in everyone getting everyone else's email addresses. It may be faster but it will also result in disclosure of all emails.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think the OP wants to send bulk emails that means sending a message to many users. In cases that he wants to send many messages (each message to a specific user) the OP should use a different thread to send mail or a schedule base solution.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Anyway thank you for your comment :) hope you find the answer useful

Comment: Sending an email to many users doesn't mean distributing their addresses to all recipients. There *are* alternatives to this, like using BCC, as well as ways to avoid BCC'd messages being flagged as spam

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Let me know what's your idea about the edit :)

Comment: First, that's not the problem. Second, wrapping a synchronous operation in a Task.Run call is a *bad* idea, especially where an asynchronous operation already exists, ie [SendMailAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194001(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I want to send same message to many recepients,so should I use thread?

Comment: If you don't mind to put them all in `To`, you can use option 1. You can always use `SendMailAsync` to make your program more responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You should rather send them asynchronously using the pickup directory. Here is a good overview. http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/asp-net-using-pickup-directory-for-outgoing-e-mails

The SMTP server handles transient network connectivity issues, and retries periodically.

Comment: The same is true for any SMTP server (you forgot to mention that the OP would have to install the SMTP Service on the machine). Why do you assume that eg Exchange can't handle the load already? Finally, using a local SMTP service *doesn't mean they are sent asynchronously* - if you use the synchronous `Send` message, the operation will be synchronous